# wp8 background gps tracker stop working

Tags: windows-phone-8, background, gps

I want to implement an application for Windows Phone 8 in order to get and send the device location data to a server every minute.

For that I have followed this example:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Instead of using:

```
App.Geolocator.MovementThreshold = 100;
```

I use:

```
App.Geolocator.ReportInterval = 1 *60 * 1000;
```

The app works well in foreground.

If I press START button the app works well too but with the following limitations:

1. If I open another appication, the backgroud gps tracker stop working.
2. After one hour aproximately, or more, the background gps tracker stop working too.

I have read that apps running in background can be deactivated by the system due the some factors:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Is there any way or a strategy to assure my gps tracker keep working in background under the above two conditions? Currently is there any wp8 application working under this conditions? It is possible or not to do this in wp8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add this snippet in `WMAppManifest.xml` in order to keep GPS running in background:

```
   <Tasks>
       <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="GUI/Register.xaml">
          <BackgroundExecution>
             <ExecutionType Name="LocationTracking" />
          </BackgroundExecution>
       </DefaultTask>
   </Tasks>
```

Add this to be able to run app in background after 1hr at last line of `App()`:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already used this snippet in my code as you can see in the first link I have referenced: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx - My app works in background but with the limitations I have written above.

Comment: ohh...please check, I have edited my answer to be able your app to run in background.

Comment: was ApplicationIdleDetectionMode solved your problem?

Comment: I have implemented your solution but I have also corrected others errros. I have corrected some unexpected errors (validations when no internet connection for example) in the background gps service, maybe this errors caused the service to stop working. Now the gps background service is working well during four hours.

Comment: Ok...means now you will be able to use app in background ...great!!